# React. Как запускать обновление страницы после каждого обновления на сервере?

Tags: reactjs

Предположим, на сервере кто-то решил увеличить массив, а на клиенте он все еще старого размера.
Как заставить страницу увидеть изменения на сервере и вызвать ее обновление?

Comment: WebSocket Вам в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Сервер по определению дает отклик только по запросу клиента. Так что если у вас это разные приложения (в рамках одного можно было бы использовать паттерн наблюдатель) - то можно только в клиенте сделать компонент, который периодически опрашивает сервер, и обновляет другие компоненты